# Paypal works fine when it set to sandbox but when turn it to live not

Tags: python, django, paypal, sdk

When I tried this which altering the client id from sandbox client id to live client id it start displaying the pop up and close it immediately while it was working fine in the sandbox.
**Note:** this a django webapp it's an ecommerce website

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=live_client_id&currency=USD"></script>
```

I really don't know what should I do, I think this should work properly because the provided client id is the same that I got in Paypal

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=live_client_id"></script>
```

I tried removing the currency and put it again but it didn't work as expected.

After I checked the network in my console I got this following errors:

(blocked:other)

> Error: /v2/checkout/orders returned status 422 (Co…hyvt1Pc-bOzp2arw77jodnU4qUPe989axhyP_6lmo:3:91397', timestamp: '1688493266180', referer: 'www.paypal.com', sdkCorrelationID: 'f97964123948a', sessionID: 'uid_60c9daccb1_mtc6mzq6nd

also in the Paypal I found those issues.

Description:The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.

I think this should work fine because very thing is good as I know.

Answer (score 0):

When changing the client-id value from sandbox to live on the frontend, the client-id value , API secret value, and mode/API endpoint URL being posted to must also be changed on the backend to match.

The most common reasons for encountering 422 errors is if the API+secret used by the backend are not correct/invalid, or for a different environment (sandbox vs. live) than where it is attempting to create the order.